# How can i use an SQLiteAsyncConnection for Android using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to implement SQLite in a Xamarin solution using Visual Studio. However, i can not find the proper way to implement an SQLiteAsyncConnection.

I am following along a tutorial, which just passes a string to the constructor of the SQLiteAsyncConnection, however this is (no longer?) accepted. I googled to find a newer solution and almost everywhere found the solution to add a platform to the constructor, however that results in an error for me.

I think i might not have added the correct NUGet packages to the project(s). I have added the sqlite-net-pcl package to both the shared project and the android project.

I have also updated all NUGet packages today, rebuilt the solution and even deleted the /bin and /obj folder and it still is not working.

```
using System.IO;
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Async;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SQLiteTest.Droid;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLiteDB))]

namespace SQLiteTest
{
    public class SQLiteDB : ISQLiteDB
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection()
        {
            const string fileName = "test.db3";

            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);

            var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            var cwLock = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(platform, new SQLiteConnectionString(path, true));
            var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => cwLock);

            return connection;
        }


    }
}
```

The error i get is:

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'SQLite.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) SQLiteTest.Android  D:\Mobile Apps\Mosh\SQLiteTest\SQLiteTest\SQLiteTest.Android\SQLiteDB.cs

Comment: Which version/fork of `sqlite-net-pcl` are you using? The most popular one is: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: @SushiHangover that fixed the problem in a way i didn't expect it would. I had the one you mentioned installed, but decided to try a different one. After switching to https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL the problem seems to be fixed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am pretty sure you have not added the `SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll` package to your native Android project which is causing this issue when you use this dependency service.

If you are using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and or [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) look for the Xamarin.Android platform dll int he path below:

```
 packages\SQLite.Net-PCL.3.1.1\lib\MonoAndroid\`SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll`
```

Comment: SQLite.NET-PCL is deprecated .. you have to look for sqlite-net-pcl instead; its IS difficult to find, but it IS there ... somewhere ..

Comment: @RichardHammond The answer is four years old...

Comment: The answer may be four years old, but software 'wears out' just like other commodities. You can learn something new every day if you have an open mind ...

Comment: This is the new library https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl

Comment: Which is what my original comment stated!